# How IMAGE_DOS_HEADER works

Tags: c++, portable-executable

```c
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntheaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(PCHAR(virtualpointer) + PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(virtualpointer)->e_lfanew);
```

In the code above, `virtualpointer` points to a memory location that has a PE file loaded.

Why is `virtualpointer` in brackets in front of `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER`?

How does it handle the pointer, and how is `e_lfanew` getting its value?

I understand the bigger picture that, in the end, `ntheaders` is getting a memory address that points to the location `0x3c` where the `NT_HEADER` is present, but how is the code working? What's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Simple pointer arithmetic. Base + Offset.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am confused about "PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(virtualpointer)->e_lfanew". What is happening here ? We could just simply have written 0x3c as well .

Comment: Just a cast to a pointer to that particular struct to be able to access that member. Hard coding it might work but it also might change someday so there's no good reason not to just do it the right way.

Comment: `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(virtualpointer)` is equivalent to `(PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)virtualpointer`, so it's just a different way of writing the cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type(value)` is a *function-style* cast, whereas `(type)valu` is a *C-style* cast.  But they are both just type-casts nonetheless (for purposes of this code, anyway).

So, in this statement:

```c
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntheaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(PCHAR(virtualpointer) + PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(virtualpointer)->e_lfanew);
```

- `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(virtualpointer)` is type-casting `virtualpointer` to an `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*` pointer. Let's call this `dos`.
- `PCHAR(virtualpointer)` is type-casting `virtualpointer` to a `char*` pointer. Let's call this `pc`.
- `pc + dos->e_lfanew` is using *pointer arithmetic* to advance the value of `pc` by the number of `char`s (ie bytes, in this case) specified in `e_lfanew`, which contains the *offset* of an `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` struct from the start of the PE.
- `(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(pc + dos->e_lfanew)` is type-casting the result of that arithmetic to an `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*` pointer.

So, the code is merely taking the starting address stored in `virtualpointer`, reading the `e_lfanew` field of the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` located at the front of that memory, advancing forward by the specified number of bytes, and then accessing the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` located at that new location.

You should read [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/february/inside-windows-win32-portable-executable-file-format-in-detail) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful answer.